# C# windows form getting cut when remotely logging in to dev machine

Tags: winforms, size, rdp

my windows form size is 1305,617.

When I remote login into my dev machine the windows form size gets cut down to 1036,617 and I am unable to widen it beyond 1036. I have tried with a bigger monitor but same issue

Any idea why?? and how to fix it?
I am using framework 2.0 C#

Answer (score 0):

So I increased the resolution of the monitor I was using to RDP and that fixed the problem.